# Cannot crop the image with correct location or original x,y.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can get the location of top,left,width,height, but I can't crop as the alert show.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#crop").click(function(){

            var canvas=document.getElementById("Mystore1");
            var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

            var top=$('#face').offset().top;
            var left=$('#face').offset().left;
            var width=$('#face').width();
            var height=$('#face').height();
            alert(top);
            alert(left);
            alert(width);
            alert(height);
            var imageSrc ='../../../Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Desert.jpg';                
            var imageObj=new Image();
            imageObj.onload=function(){
                context.drawImage(imageObj, top, left, width, height, top, left, width, height);
            };
            imageObj.src=imageSrc;
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Possible this may what you want, Look at [This][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200374/copy-and-crop-images-in-javascript

Comment: what alert is showing?

Comment: it shows the alert of top,left,width,height and it shows the correct values of where I want to crop, but when I crop the image it were wrong location.

Comment: have you look at [this](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/git/pixastic/actions/crop.js) and [this](https://gist.github.com/murz/702799)

Comment: Can you tell me more detail about this? or can you tell me about what is the problem of my coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an working demo. i found some problem in your code. on ready function param you should 
send `$` and on click an event variable named `e` (whatever you want).

[image: demontraiton]

croparea is the face area selected by your crop tool. main image is the image portion. 
your js should be like so

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {

        $("#crop").click(function(e){
        var Imgwidth = $('#face').width(), 
            Imgheight =  $('#face').height(),
            faceOffset = $('#face').offset(),
            imgOffset = $('#imgHolder').find('img').offset(), 
            imgX1 = faceOffset.left-imgOffset.left,
            imgY1 = faceOffset.top-imgOffset.top,
            imgX2 =imgX1+Imgwidth,
            imgY2 = imgY1+Imgheight;


         var imageSrc ='http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';    
          var imageObj=new Image();
          imageObj.src=imageSrc; 
        selx1 = imgX1;
        sely1 = imgY1;
        selx2 = imgX2;
        sely2 = imgY2;
        selw = Imgwidth;
        selh = Imgheight;
        console.log(imgX1);
        console.log(imgY1);
        /*console.log(imgX2);
        console.log(imgY2);*/
        var canvas=document.getElementById("Mystore1");
        var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.canvas.height = Imgheight;

        context.drawImage(imageObj, imgX1, imgY1, selw, selh, 3, 3, Imgwidth, canvas.height-5);


        });
    });
```

when you select an area ( here #face div) from an image to crop then i calculate the top-left(X,Y) co-ordinate of the selected area in this line

```
imgX1 = faceOffset.left-imgOffset.left,
imgY1 = faceOffset.top-imgOffset.top,
```

and the right-bottom co-ordinate in these line

```
imgX2 =imgX1+Imgwidth,
imgY2 = imgY1+Imgheight;
```

and thus we get a rectangular co-ordinate system to draw the portion of the image that we selected to crop. for `drawImage` documentation please go to the link that i post in comment. i hope now its clear how i get the exact position to crop.

here is a working demo [click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/h4QPUx8QAXlhwfMuKeuz)

Comment: Thank you...but this demo not working for me, because I want to use a crop tools to crop the image, not define value for it.

Comment: okay you can see `http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-image-crop/` for more. as you said you are using crop image tool, you need to get the initial co-ordinate (left-top) and the the end  (right-bottom) coordinate and calculate the height and width dynamically from it. then just draw it on canvas. you can set drawing origin for better placement.

Comment: I think you still don't understand my purpose yet. For example: I have a crop tools and I want to crop the where I want to crop, but when I crop on location of top 80, left 100, width 80, height 80, accidentally it shows the crop location with different location where I have crop. and my code is as above. I really need help from you. Thank you.

Comment: please check this [updated plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/h4QPUx8QAXlhwfMuKeuz) . i hope this helps you

Comment: Sorry sir, can you give with a very clear sample one, i'm too new with this. thank you.

Comment: pls check the answer,i edited it with explanation. i hope its clear now

Comment: Hello sir. Can I bother you again? I have seen your code and it work well, but when I added some more function it seems to crop wrong again. For example: I added function rotate Left or Right it crop wrongly. Here is my function rotate (I used jqueryrotate as library)
>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> 
 alert('hello');
 var loop=0; 
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#left").click(function(){
   loop +=90;
     $("#imgHolder").rotate({ animateTo:loop });
   });
   });
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $("#right").click(function(){
    loop-=90;
         $("#imgHolder").rotate({animateTo:loop});
     });
  });
 </script